Frequency Modulation
I'm trying to understand the role of a constant in frequency modulation.
What I understand:
Frequency modulation results from a signal where the angular frequency $$\omega(t)$$ is the sum of the carrier wave's angular frequency $$\omega_0$$ and the input modulating signal $$e_m(t)$$
So we have the frequency as
$$\omega(t) = \omega_0 + e_m(t)$$
Thus, in its cosine form, the modulated signal corresponds to the cosine of the integral of this sum.
\begin{align*}
e(t)
&= \cos\left(\int_0^t \omega(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)\\
&=\cos\left(\int_0^t \omega_0 + e_m(t)\right)\\
&= \cos\left(\omega_0 t + \int_0^t e_m(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)
\end{align*}
Although this assumption makes sense to me, all references state that the angular frequency of the modulated signal is the sum of the carrier wave's angular frequency and the input modulating signal multiplied by a constant $$K_{\mathrm{f}}$$
So we have the frequency as
$$\omega(t) = \omega_0 + K_{\mathrm{f}} e_m(t)$$
Why is this constant necessary?

My doubt is if the constant is necessary. If so, why? Would it work without the constant?

No, it's not necessary, you can use 1.

So am I correct to assume the constant is not a Theoretical definition but yes for practical usage? Let's say the amplitude of the input is way to large that I want to reduce it's impact in modulated frequency, in these cases I use the constant. (Sorry for bad english)

It's only about converting volts to hz. can be 1Hz/V, can be something else

The constant isn't necessary -- it's just how a given author wishes to define the signal.
If you want \$e(t)\$ to fit some sensible (to you) scheme like \$e(t) = \cos \omega_a t\$, then you'd need \$K_f\$ to set the modulation index you want to use.
On the other hand, if you want to use \$e(t)\$ without \$K_f\$, then you'd need to put constraints on the amplitude (and if you're being strict about it) units of \$e(t)\$ to make it all work.

If I'm writing a text about it, can I define the modulation function without the constant and state that, for practical uses, a constant is desirable to limit the frequency variation range?

Yes, but if you have to ask you may want to get a few more years' worth of confidence before you start typing.

Of course! I'm just writing the theoretical introduction for a bachelor's telecommunication subject and would like to be precise about the reason for using this constant

@NicolasSantos I'd say you're in the state of writing your own lecture notes, and that's very fine, and you're asking the right questions! But your understanding is not yet that of someone who should write a theoretical intro for Bachelor students, I'm afraid :) There's so many good texts out there, though, so don't reinvent the wheel! There's really 80 years of people explaining FM to undergrad students, so there's no pressure on you to write a new text :)

Indeed.  While you're consulting texts, go visit your university library and browse through a few copies of the ARRL Handbook and/or the GBRC Handbook.  There are excellent explanations in there that have been used by thousands of engineers to build working systems.

There was a misunderstanding, . I'm a student. The text I'm writing is for a telecommunication's homework. I'm pretty sure I have a long path before starting to make my own contributions. (I'm Brazilian, so this explains the errors I committed while writing and caused this misunderstanding)

@TimWescott, thanks for the references. Surely I'll take a look at them. Probably is hard to find them here at my country, but I'll browse for it on internet!

The constant is for doing the math.
For example, an FM radio broadcast must have +/- 75 kHz deviation from the carrier for a full scale signal. Depending on what is your signal em(t) and how it is defined, you  need the constant to bring the modulation to +/- 75 kHz. The signal em(t) could be analog audio which has units of maximum amplitude of 2 Vrms in volts, or digital audio with 16-bit integers between -32768 to +32767, or floating point numbers between +/- 1.
